# Show Details About Row Selected from Table Images

Tags: tableview

I have question about didselectrow 
If I have screen contains table of images , I want user choose one image and the details will appear (labels, image) and navigation bar will show user name too ,Please I need help to organise my ideas .
What about code too?

thank you very much

Comment: programming by swift language